# Wifi disconnected before init.d script is run

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-s3, init.d

I've set up a simple init.d script "S3logrotate" to run on shutdown. The "S3logrotate" script works fine when run manually from command line but the script does not function correctly on shut down.

The script uploads logs from my PC to an Amazon S3 bucket and requires wifi to run correctly.

Debugging proved that the script is actually run but the upload process fails.

I found that the problem seems to be that the script seems to run after wifi is terminated.

These are the blocks I used to test my internet connection in the script.

```
if ping -q -c 1 -W 1 8.8.8.8 >/dev/null; then
  echo "IPv4 is up" >> *x.txt*
else
  echo "IPv4 is down" >> *x.txt*
fi

if ping -q -c 1 -W 1 google.com >/dev/null; then
  echo "The network is up" >> *x.txt*
else
  echo "The network is down" >> *x.txt*
fi
```

The output for this block is:

```
IPv4 is down
The network is down
```

Is there any way to set the priority of an init.d script? As in, can I make my script run before the network connection is terminated? If not, is there any alternative to init.d?

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and have dual booted with Windows 10 if that's significant.

Thanks,

sganesan7

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites  http://askubuntu.com OR  http://superuser.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: The link in `/etc/rc6.d` should have a numeric prefix like `K01`. The scripts are run in numeric order, so you should give it a lower number than the script that terminates the network connection.

Answer (score 0):

You should place you scrip in:

```
/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/pre-down.d
```

change group and owner to root

```
chown root:root S3logrotate
```

and it should work. If you need to do this for separate interface place script in

create a script inside

```
/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/
```

and name it (for example):

```
 wlan0-down
```

and should work too.